# Para muestra basta un [botón]

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Hoy he encontrado que tenemos el tag [button](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/button) con 29 preguntas, mientras que [boton](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boton) tiene 18.

Creo que lo correcto sería tener el [botón](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bot%c3%b3n) y que [button](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/button) fuera un sinónimo de este.

¿Qué les parece?

Comment: ¿Dónde está el botón "sí, adelante"? :)

Comment: ¿Deberían [tag:botón]/[tag:button] considerarse meta-etiquetas? ¿Realmente proveen información clave para la pregunta? Porque en la mayoría de los casos que he visto son realmente circunstanciales (el elemento principal es un botón, pero podría ser un enlace o un label y la pregunta se respondería igual o casi)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro: Yo creo que sí deberían considerarse meta-etiquetas. No veo un contexto en el que podría usarse como única etiqueta de la pregunta, me parece que siempre deberán acompañarse de una etiqueta de lenguaje.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro yo creo que esa propuesta se deberia agregar como respuesta aqui

Comment: @jasilva ¿dentro de esta misma pregunta?¿o como una pregunta separada? (No quiero "secuestrar" tu publicación con un tema relacionado pero no exactamente igual)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro yo creo que esta bien aqui ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He creado los siguientes sinónimos de etiqueta (manteniendo [botón](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bot%c3%b3n) como maestro):

- [botón](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bot%c3%b3n) ← [boton](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boton) (19 preguntas)
- [botón](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bot%c3%b3n) ← [button](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/button) (31 preguntas)

---

Todas estas etiquetas parecen meta-etiquetas ya que no proveen información clave para la pregunta y en la mayoría de los casos son realmente circunstanciales (el elemento principal es un botón, pero podría ser un enlace o un label y la pregunta se respondería igual o casi) y/o deberían ir acompañadas de una etiqueta de lenguaje para que tengan sentido.

Quizás deberíamos plantearnos que no se puedan utilizar directamente.