# Quemar y banear la etiqueta [botón]

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, solicitud-de-quemado

Actualización: [botón](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bot%c3%b3n) ← [boton](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boton)

---

Las estadísticas de uso dicen que es una etiqueta con ¡+80 preguntas!

Por si sola, no tiene ningun sentido, ya que un boton puede tomar diferentes formas dependiendo la view donde se lo use, y tambien del lenguaje. Tampoco hace diferencia sobre que sea un boton lo que se presione, una imagen, u otro tipo de control.

Acompaña a etiquetas como [c#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), [html](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), [java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), [angular](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular), [c++](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), [unity](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity), [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python).

Ejemplos:

[Ejecutar un .m desde una GUI de MATLAB y guardar sus variables en el workspace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/86114/ejecutar-un-m-desde-una-gui-de-matlab-y-guardar-sus-variables-en-el-workspace)

[Click en botón con Selenium webdrive](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/94551/click-en-bot%c3%b3n-con-selenium-webdrive)

[Botón que coja la posición de la siguiente palabra y la resalte](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/110610/bot%c3%b3n-que-coja-la-posici%c3%b3n-de-la-siguiente-palabra-y-la-resalte)

[Uncaught ReferenceError: url is not defined en la linea url: url + 'eliminar_contacto_empresa.php',](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/102493/uncaught-referenceerror-url-is-not-defined-en-la-linea-url-url-eliminar-con)

[¿Como puedo hacer un botón en en canvas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/61853/como-puedo-hacer-un-bot%c3%b3n-en-en-canvas)

[¿Cómo puedo acceder a un campo o botón solo con tabulador con css y materialize?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/78898/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-acceder-a-un-campo-o-bot%c3%b3n-solo-con-tabulador-con-css-y-materialize)

[pasar a un fragmet mediante un bottonbar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/71713/pasar-a-un-fragmet-mediante-un-bottonbar)

Esta etiqueta debería morir en el infierno de las etiquetas quemadas.

Comment: totalmente de acuerdo, mucha gente te pondra boton, cuando la solucion es un link etc... como descripcion ok, pero como etiqueta no creo que sea lo mas adecuado.

Comment: Refloto esto.. existe la etiqueta [tag:botón].. que deberia morir tambien... y para colmo tiene como 89 preguntas!

Comment: 1 mes antes de esta solicitud, se habían creado los sinónimos en [Para muestra basta un \[botón\]](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2758/127)

Comment: si lo se.. pero justamente no entiendo el sentido.. es una meta etiqueta.. por si sola no vale nada...Fijate que en esa misma pregunta Alvaro pregunta si tiene algun sentido

Comment: ¿Qué opinas del uso de [tag:botón] en [¿Como en crear un botón HTML que funcione como un link?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/48805/65) ¿Qué le sugerirías al OP? :D

Comment: Me pregunto si los 16 votos positivos son porque está muy bien hecha la pregunta / se encuentra útil o porque se está a favor.

Comment: Habria que sacar la etiqueta  oton de alli. Definitivamente el autor no tenia conciencia de lo que hacia. (Sigo opinando que la etiqueta no tiene sentido de ser). Respecto de los 16... ni idea... pero es la de quemar que mas tiene. Si la reinicio, me la van a cerrar por duplicada...

Comment: ¿Has revisaso [Criterios para la solicitud-de-quemado](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2839/65)?

Comment: Es **UNA** de las de quemar que más tiene (ejem!) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Alternativa 1

Se debe erradicar [botón](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bot%c3%b3n) de todas las preguntas e incluir en la lista negra.

Answer (score 0):

Alternativa 2

Se debe "perdonar" a [botón](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bot%c3%b3n) y dejar que continúe su uso por quien lo considere necesario

Comment: Me parece que [tag:botón] no cumple con los criterios especificados en [¿Cuál es el proceso de remover etiquetas (quemarlas)?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2839/65), concretamente no hace daños serios. Mi voto es por dejarla como está.